# Install Pybrain Anaconda env

Tags: installation, anaconda, pybrain

I need to install Pybrain package in my Anaconda environment (Pybrain is not part of Anaconda distribution). I use Pycharm and it has always been easy to install packages since they were all available in Anaconda distribution.

Do you have any idea about how to do it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Here are third party conda packages for pybrain: https://anaconda.org/search?q=Pybrain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
<Anaconda installation dir>\Anaconda\Scripts\pip.exe install https://github.com/pybrain/pybrain/archive/0.3.3.zip
```

For example for Windows version:

```
D:\Programs\Anaconda\Scripts\pip.exe  install https://github.com/pybrain/pybrain/archive/0.3.3.zip
```